Purpose of bypass loop heading into analog front-end?
How do the 285k ohm and 4.2 nF components achieve filtering in this diagram?

Generally speaking, an RC filter with these values would produce ~133Hz low-pass filtering.
Does this still accomplish filtering with expected cutoff freq?
Or is the loop only intended to be active perhaps if the 0F capacitor gets blown?
Note that the 0pF cap could sit after the 285k connection point, which would make sense as a last ditch fuse-like protection method.



As drawn the 285 k resistor and the 4.2 nF cap do nothing.  There's no current through them nor voltage across them so they have no effect on the circuit.  Are you missing a connection or ground?

Where did you get this diagram from? The diagram is not finished. Connections are missing. It's useless as shown/

@JohnD there's another patient contact which heads into the inverting input and a totally separate patient "ground" which pushes the patient DC voltage toward mid-supply voltage of the ADS1299. Current is ideally zero into the amplifier, but in reality is never quite true. There is a 1M (typically) input impedance on the amp. Also a TI TPD4E1B06DCKR ESD Protection device in front of the 5k, since voltage/current jumps could otherwise damage the board, but does not seem quite relevant.

Call the loose line on the left of diagram "Actual connection" A. What resistance do you measure from A to the pin on the chip?

Is the "0 pF" capacitor actually a capacitor, or could it be a fuse of some sort?  If the device opens then it would certainly limit current to the patient, so it might be a safety feature in case of a fault in the amplifier.  Though not clear why the fuse opening wouldn't be sufficient on its own.  It may help to detect the fault somehow to have the extra components, so that would be a desirable feature.

@JohnD and Kuba, you were right, the dead loop cap is connected to Ground -- updated the question diagram. This diagram comes from inspecting/probing a board.

@AndrewMorton it measures as 5k from far left input to pin-on-chip.

Thank you for your patience -- the edits depict a more fully connected circuit, which I should have done in the first place. Was an unworthy initial post.

The 0F capacitor is shorted in your own first schematic, and absent altogether in the following ones, and the circuit is a bit hard to parse drawn that way, so let me rearrange it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
V1 is whatever input potential \$V_{IN}\$ is applied at IN. Clearly R1 and R2 form a potential divider, for which we can find the Thevenin equivalent:
$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{TH} &= R_1 \parallel R_2 \\ \\
&= \frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
&= 4.9k\Omega \\ \\
V_{TH} &= V_{IN} \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{57}{58} V_{IN}
\end{aligned}
$$

simulate this circuit
So \$V_{IN}\$ is very slightly attenuated. From this equivalent it's trivial to find the cut-off frequency \$f_C\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_C &= \frac{1}{2\pi R_{TH}C_1} \\ \\
&= 7.7 \rm{\ kHz} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Thank you -- do you know why the original circuit when simulated shows a -3dB point of ~7579Hz, which is what the cutoff frequency would be with an exact 5k resistor?

Here is the original, showing -3DB point at ~7445Hz, which corresponds to Rth=(290/285)*R1 = (58/57)*R1 ~= 5.1k
https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDMB0YEwFYCmBaA7OADATmgNj0kjAQA4AWOCsvEU0kBEcyR1MMAKADc7Nxy5Pswb8IaQUwj8Z0BJwBO4PP3IM45VaMaZdnAMYgNWo5vDwQq6HFTZLsPOTTYEiMHgQkEkUtOi6uJUg4E2CxC34qBF1MTgB3U1CQkUtOAHMoZI44TLEVS1SE43McsJLCxKhMITLIatSM2vra1wLYorNisuLYoOSu5LqhSNJovUNiybMhgvJrWxB0ayI8VGI7TH9MQOVIzv2ZHT0AQxF+R0ZsHIu7ZJQsmJjFtGXIVZR1grB23JTydxSP26ZjU-FIMniwjUu0BkPBAiExWyqQADpUUAC3gwMbRWBC0e4TPCwIIoG1IcVocUcRUysiseUgXgGPTmYsAbEAPbgOwXVQ4dRyezScCcblgBh85gC8DWJibCCKzhAA

Here is Thevenin using Rth = (58/57)*R1 = 5.01k, with -3DB at F=7445Hz.
https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDMB0YEwFYCmBaA7OADATmgNj0kjAQA4AWOCsvEU0kBEcyR1MMAKADc7Nxy5Pswb8IaQU0zRspOOQR4w5TJASY0pEiH67oCTgCdwefuQbyzoxplJpOAYxCWRzleHg7m0OKmw78PFIgtE04VUE8NCloTEwuYxY4cCpmSGSwbGT+KjjSTE4AdzcrKEwhcx1OAHMocI9k9LFTLwLilw5G+s6q9vdIcrr+AaEC2qayoQm1bN6S+YmXAsS8IRRV5g3dZ1J1OMd5lxcRr3IfPxAUaTVMcLRwijA7NGUAuISTHPcj9zNsMBgaGwxFUkGw4PBnAAhmlkhsEGhaBt-PUUN04hjtmI2kN5uQwLR8nMiZUCaUcUTlEIOp4CgAHKAIZIodLzFmNVqcBlk1yUwRQTl9UoudlzCY9GYNMVMqWS0U4yUSwY9AoAe3ADC2zBwDDAPhiEDEnHVYAwWpUsnA+oCEFtnCAA

Simulation is identical in terms of power and cutoff frequency, suggesting that Rth = (58/57)*R1 = R1 * (Vin/Vth)

Oh, I see. Original circuit -3dB point is indeed ~7712, because it's -3dB FROM the baseline Vout when f is DC or low-freq (at DC, Vout=Vin*57/58).
Originally I was setting f in the simulator until I saw 0.707V on Vout and calling that Fc.
In the simulator, I should instead be confirming the Fc value which produces Vout = 1V*(57/58)/(sqrt(2)) ~~ 0.695V (not 0.707V), which is -3dB with respect to low or DC inputs.
This was my fundamental misunderstanding -- learned a lot here, thanks!
